# How can I insert images into a webpage by only using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to insert url of some image from another website into css without using html? 
tried this

```
content:url(url);
```

and also used `background-image` instead of `content`. When I run it on Internet Explorer and Chrome, images are not visible on web page. I am not allowed to edit the HTML code.

Comment: Use `background-image` & make sure the element you are using has some dimentions. Then use Firebug for Firefox or Developer Tools for Chrome to debug. You will be able to use those tools to determine if your url is correct, the resource is loaded, the size of the element and the other styles applied to your target element.

Comment: I think hotlinking is disabled by that website

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS. without that we can't help you.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
  .className{
    background-image:url('your url here');
    width:500px; //use your pixels
  height:500px;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcpDV/1/)

Comment: tried that but images are not visible when i run the page  on a browser

Comment: @user3385608: specify width and height

Comment: I did..but picture not visible on browser

Comment: @user3385608 can you post your css and html

Answer (score 3):

Only CSS? You can use Base64 encode and use CSS like below.

```
<img src="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" id="YTLogo" />


#YTLogo {
    width: 392px;
    height: 170px;
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAYgAAACqCAYAAAC3UNivAABNgklEQVR42u1dd5gWtdb//v+uV68N6SwsZVm2K6KCIkVBRFS4FkQUUFF6b0tHQDpIX3pn6b0uvZdd6oJUKVKsV1DBdr98OTOTmUwmM0ned2FbeJ7fc8Jk5uScJOf8kpl3Zv/nqaeeQhoaGhoaGiz+R3eChoaGhoYmCA0NDQ0NTRAaGhoaGpogNDQ0NDQ0QWhoaGhoaILQ0NDQ0NAEoaGhoaGhCUJDQ0NDQxOEhoaGhoYmCA0NDQ0NTRAaGhoaGpogNDQ0NDQ0QWhoaGhoaGiC0NC4N3jySVQZozrGq08moQYYjTA+wvgMo21SIuqE0R2jT1IS+jwxEQ3FGIUxLjEJTcJyCsZ0jFkYcxMS0UIsF2O5DGMVLq/Bch2W6zE2YmzGSMPYirEdYyfGLgq7LexhsJfBvgQT+xOSbMD/D1D/P2AdI3XkWqJzd0KC0dZOLA3g8g4sd1i2AbZZ2GLZvtHyZQ3GaowVGMsxlmAsxG3Mw3ImltMwUnB5PMaXGCOtvoM+7I37shvu0w4YrXE/N8dogtEQj0N9LOtgwJg8i6HnqSYIDY2w8DROJDUx3rAS/KcYHZPMRDTUSlIzjcSdYCS2NEiMGIdx4kyPT0QZWALSKSmFeErGM8cYnTx42sO22JIuS9az7Yn0Z+QC/w/GmyS6CWMlHjMg4OlYjsVyMEZPjPZ4rIHU38Woi1ENz4WK+ZRcNEFo5CtAsL9trTI7J5krUFi9z7YSBqxyD/slVMWExuKwpQskD/Q5PP2mXaFfL7JPSCj52P9DGLDrWYYxA2M0Rr9Ec9fSDM+lNzEq50ES0QShkafxGg7cXjiQZxu3PUgySbKQSElvghElNLcOrz623tQVlDBF5zuSD7Z9NXu1/+H7vxnPsclAHBjV8wBhaILQyHOoggOzi3VP2whgCHIS6CoBn0BJ7vXBCecQJQ8xx3gQn+9u75BV9j2ftln7f9/9PxAPz5ES0Cd4kZJbb1FpgtDIM4CHkL0Tk4wHo2bSSKIkRlyiI+Os5BLnn3DM8xPt813HJEDr5Oq/5+dr/3OK/2vxzqJFUqLxQwZNEBoa9xlNk5LQBhyEBxUCmJwLki77nk/Jg1biOUgnIFdSCr890fUswtWn/b/3/i/Aixd48K0JQkPjPu0aRuKgM4KcBHs8U46ThOh6T32CI+MsG2zpTTiiBCcG3Ya3Pe1/7vB/T3wC6piYqAlCQ+NeAh4CLsbBdgAHnokESpqBeiAggRywApyc79ZBzqHPd+QBS+eBgIRD20C3Ja1PkLDoa7T/uc//MXhhUymH33LSBKGRK1ELb9PXxye4AtoLd8JgE4Bq/X5K7rfq9ivpc4PWIaePRaL2P5f7PxOTxDM5mCQ0QWjkOtS0yMEMVCfBsGADWJSQ2HqxPkc6dgToj02wpYE4SkrZQ7eRqP3PI/7PTIg3Xs7UBKGhkQU/YV0WF4/2xZrBSCRdBsnDfkruJ9cFXA8BvI9KYK6kxuiUOZ9NiGzC87Yf7J/2P+/4PzYhUROEhka4mBSfIJ8g4hMdSZd9EogHcZSMs66NC9DHnk8fCyGhiaD9z1v+d05I0AShoREqOiS4A3hvnCMNxMY7ki7HJXBB6+AF+F5KylzP2iOqZ+016iwpA+1/3vJ/N94Zv/5koiYIDY1Qnjtsi4sPDPg8B8WEp/3P/UjFczwnvXWtCUIjV2BcfALag5PDHhxAhrQSxR4qYdDHQoFQXxwl4+LDt0egL8vb0/7nCv/b5aBbTZogNHI8Xk9KRLusoNodFORhJhy2fnesI3fz2g/zfBGE+rT/edL/9Rg55W9XaILQyAW7B3fw+QVkVoMNcPpYdkD7n3/8zym7CE0QGjkaNZ5MQjti44wdhAcV4hyJsdsqkyDbRcldzDEe7vn5lI08iOzX/ucf/5fiOa8JQkNDgK54JbUrKEkEJAwP6HMwdlplkHTZT99OSsqcz7Z3z6H9z1P+109K1AShoRGEeTGxdkDuJMEM0ijHOrICOS/WN4DZhCCC6Hqxftomr31eCM7X/ucr/wfEx2uC0NDwQ1W4vYQDZgcOlh1W8OwISBg7rIThdz59jF/vSKdd53wWqvpZeM6nfJDxR/uft/1PxYujfEEQr776Kpo5c6Yypk6dmmU2NG7cOCQb6tWrp5N1NuGjxEQqWMUB6z6Hd75qfZyg/XvdXpz2P5/7Xy2b/3bEfSGIZ555Bt2+fRuF8u+dd97JEhsWL16s3PYff/yBnn/+eZ2sswl94+PQ9uhYtL2ChWhKRjPHMK7Nn4eupS5E11NTDZAySBnQ14Ryvay+HfEJfH9YMP6J/IeEsp1KOFBHpIw++hre9XtwLKj4f2X6NLc+ysbc6L/QHgYefSH43zib/27EfSGIJ+G7/YsWhUQQI0eOzBIbLl68qNz2tm3bUGIu+cMeeREpMTFoGw6UbRUsRFOSg//++QfKDf+2JyT5+uAC7bOE/yJsr+BIuix7/b5atZX8/P3770K2NSf6f9+BbeuWzb9mum/PIJo2aRJSMO3evTvstmvXrh1S23369NGJOruAFxVrrUDZaiOGkjFWXYwdUH//kTsIYkt8ost2P3+2KvrPQqxfrf1tL7+s5Ocv331L2ezWmRv9F7XP6nNfE5r/YyvE5A+CiIuLQz/88INyMN25c8e4RRVO27179w4pkGtUr64TdXb9QaCkJCow/eAO2NxCEJvjEtAWy+YtdjLxJhRV/8XXh3f+tpdrhUUQW6zyFsrv3OR/uOeH4v/y6HxCEHCrZs6cOSEF1GeffRZW2ytXrlRu8+TJkyghB35+N988oE6IdwUVL8C22OVYA7mHIBJtm92gfYpR9p+9XgRV/VtVdxDffsu0ydqbu/xX1e9FaP5n54Pq+/oz1/caNgwpoGbMmBFWuzdu3FBuc+yXXxrPTnSyzh4kx8SiNBwcQYBgSrtPBPF///d/tqTLIRFEfCI3IaRRUgas/94EFpzgRO2x+rfiHYSK/yZBxErbm9P9Z0GfwztfVC9rT8NsfA56XwkiJiYGXb9+XTnwMjMzQ27zzTffDCkR/LtBA52osxEjoytIJwqC3LKD2BSXYNi7OSrGlnRZ1W8CkT5xe7GUjGWO4eT1kvoOIi0qdHtzmv/C66MoGcUcC8P/1rGx+YMgkpKSjHcbVBP2f//7X1Q9xOcBgwYNUl7p3bx5E8XngLcY8zPmYIJgA8iDaEpi/PX77/dlBxDuv42YIFy2SyY0kf8ipFEyjTnGs4fVHwpBBNqUy/wX2svqE0HS/77Z+KD6vr9JXb9+/ZACt3v37iG1t3HjxsBEwGt/3rx5+vZSNgL+YMpaK3g2lXcCalNUBVvSZVIfzg5ClUDCIZyNsfGm3VExtjTK5R1J/Fbxn6039BBJl33qRe3RBCHjPyEIv/Zzm/8ee6ljXHsoneH4PxYvlvINQcTi7dKlS5eUA3j58uUhtffTTz8pt9W8eXOdqLPzr8fhnaZMQLP193MHEQ6hbIhNMO0mySOaKUsmNGE9C1F7LBj9oRDExvJh2JPD/BfpJ76CpMvh+r+gfHT+IQi4zTRu3DjpiUbK165dU26rYcOGyoH822+/6d1DNuPthAQ7yGiIAi63PIPYgHcQpk8xlIxhjqn7zyaojVGUjGKOSdSz7aW99JLyLaYgf3Kb/2L9MY6U8EfW//VYZ6VsyknZ8rG+unXrhrSSg9tTKu2MGDHCbke2PbglBSSmE3X24dO4OHewWQG4gZI8AEGIFhry9Y40gSgZ3o5ifUw8137wdQOdYBT9h2SyITABsgnMDdoGnr60gGcQPP9vf3vTlfBonbnRfzahe89n7GcSfjj+v5RNOSlbCAJuM505c0ZqotEYMmSIUjs7d+5UvlWQ3KOHTtLZjE7RVtCUp2R55hgHd2/dQn/dvWvgzzt3bEmXST2NUG41/f3XXy79LILaW4d3EDL+qPofNgTtba75klSc2gRx82Z4/uQw/++7fuqc+tn0Tla2EATcwhkxfLjvxPILWPg2kmwblSpVQr/++qvSyhF+LfXCCy/oJJ3N6Fc+Gm+ro42ttSPNYFlPBRDUbbDPiUYDihRD/WgUpWRR5hiFa8eO+SY6P6TPnevRI4s15Ryf3KB9Vvffc355R9JlfttesO1twgSh+h5EkD+5zX/6mEy9yB8V/z+Mi8s/BAF42bqfqZLA4YuwkPilvv3UtKnUrQQaGRkZ+u3pHIBRVlCsK+dIuuwXYLNKlUGzIsugmaVMkDJIuszW3zh+nLmNJL6ldHzePPP6SLH+WZFu2L5EOZIuE39U/RedH66+jTVrqt1iwjuIQP25zH/DTiKzwl4F/1tVqJC/CAK+zXT06FHhSo1N8M2aNZPSP378eGWCgF2NTtDZj2lGwFTwoly0I3mgz+Gd71N/48Rx4S0TFicxQYTanm+9CPfIf1l7NtaoKR2nUIYdRF7yP2x9YfjfIzqfEQTcZoKX2FR/bz558mQp/QcOHJCeyES+rv84UI7AIhw0a0MABNJaKuDoY0G4cfyY8kNtIIi1VqBntT1r77P/stcDQcg+1DcJ4mae8n8dJdcxx+71+A+KKp///uRotRdfNO77q9z7PXLkiFBv5cqV0e+//66k98qVK/rt6RzyktyaMiQwKlCyAnPMizWUXMMc4+lbY5VD3UGIgtprj9OmjD/3y3/Z8zcE7CD8HlLnJf/F9t678R9TLjr/EQQk5IM+K30//PXXX6hq1aqBeuHrr6oPHeHPi+r3H7Ifzz+ZZAcUEIUteaDP4QQ4IRq/80n5+vFjEgnPvUIGgvDT59seC9H598l/2fr11Wu6dghE+gEIIi/5L2r/Xo5/Stl8uIOAhNynd2/XpCI7CpB0mT6nU6dOwfewp01TJohmTZvqBJ0D8FJigh0gq8s4ki771bMQnU/KMgTB20GwAS+2t7wtTURTUt7erPZfVt96hR0EIYi85D97/v0c/9n5kSAAVSpXRn/++afvJOMRRmpqaqDOoIffXn3/Rbdu3dJ/WjSH4DW8q1yFgwawGgcHkXTZri8TbUu6TOpZsOevtoLv2rGj3IVIEE5ggmDb8+hXhEffffJfVv+66qERRF7xX2jvPRz/xWWj8ydBwG0meKGNJGwW3sD9r/EtJz99cPsJbkMF7UBYwlizZk2Wvz0NP8eFT423bNkSde7cGfXs2dPY+cDtr3r16qGKFStqQuDgrbhY3wAXBfwqSsqhvCFhByHaubL1hCBWuRJSNCWjPfVie1l998d//zbc/gBBqMQVEERe8l98/b0d/4rZcAs82wkCbjN169rVtaIn0sT/UdKZlK+99hpXX/v27W0dMoEuc8tKFvXqvYYmTpyIMjLS0R9//OFLegD45tP+/fvRqFGjUK1atbK8Xzt27Gh8lVYWQGIqn1BX0f3JJ59I6/4gJsYOmJVWwICky371oYK/g6DnnnceHp871wjalVQAr6RkKPaKzr9X/svqX1uthtKtYCAIkb1r4hLQvo8/RqfHjEaXFi5EV1asQBfnzkEn8RzbUb9Btvi/JiYe7X6vETrauxc6N2UK+nrhAnR15Up0eclidGH2bJQ5bBg60KIF2lTl+fs6/i9kw+c2/icnrBqfwavt33+/6yKHoOQKGDBgAFcXJCR64op2JHB767nnngvL/nfffde1C1JpH3wFGzZu3IDeeOONLOvTuTiBybRPygsWLJDWvW/fPmkCBsA3sWR1f1yhgh0QKyi5gjmWleARhGgcgSBW2sEbzZTFbW6rWw/dvnAe3fLB7YsXbHn7wgV0Y+tWaf/PTJrkq5eHdLw4kLEZCEJ2XpMdhJ+utJq10OWlS9Afv/wSqO/WuXPoYOs293T8AasrxKJD7Tugb3ftMj6HIhp/gp/PnMHkNgZtrPKC0vjLzG+2vkY23AbPEQQBby9v2rTJZ6K4dxSkDB/V4+mCbzyJBpUGJLtQnz88++yzRmKlb2mFA/hpbkpKCnr66afD7tNZM2cqtQ2EIqt79+7dSrqHK7yA2CI62g6I+wUgCJEPbAIEglBvK8qWaW82kJrnpP7Hr76SbufsosXCHRGt/1C/fkJ7AWsCdhC8/rp144ZH3+q4RHQez82/8aJIxf/LS5ehlVEVsn78y1VAGcnJ6DdMZirjz/r/1x9/oAvw8uTTz0qNv7ssZ2vtbPjKQ44gCLjN1KF9e6WkA3/ngb2P//LLLysn5S8GDw7J5ldeeQWdOnUK6/jb0vU3Uw6dKA4ePIiqVauWSwhC7L8KQbQt7xDE8sgoWxogZZAcrKDkCuZYUL25gwhOUCyOWQTh0iewlz5//Rv1lcbn5ulT0v6fTF2kpHtXn74+/RNlS8DqgB0ED0AQtL1ptevgHcuFkOPiysqVWTr+G1+sjn7IyJAiKFnc/fFHtK/5p8LxlwE7n+rGx+VPgjBekMKAj+tBJ//9t5NgSBkki8aNG7t0wF+dYxMUez2rv06dV0L6XPmVK5elCEHUvl/96dOnUY0aNcImCFH7xPa5c+coEsTf0v6rEESnqGi0DAfDMiuwlgUkBBb0NTyw+kj52tGjyokACMK8PirA3ihKEtIw5bo33mR0BhPtjVOnpP0/kZqq5MvOPn3Ma4kfPgS3ulp1dYKw/N/94Qfo91u3As4P9p/M2YyePbNk/Hc2bIR+//nnLNn585A5alTg+PP6l7WfnU9vxuVjgoDbTOvWreUkHP+JM3bsWJeOJUuWBBIKmyDPnTun/PY0fO31Al4F+SfcYILw2uNI1j/4uS7cxgqlP+HFP5H/4ewgVPxXIYju5XBQlLEAgRIQ8B7Q1/CuZ+stwA5CdZwIQSwLCOhllGTtWWsQxN9C4ibtwQ5C1v8TCxdKL0RMgugr1d+rjB1EcAKn9f98/brh/+5mzdCfd35z+UP3qYz/pHznhx/QqoQnwxp/05470gtRUZz6+X964kTf8Q/F/rfjYvMvQRi3F9q28UycIMD3lujrL1++LEyI9LEpKSnKb0/v2LHdNVFE9rITyxsYwfVLly4NiyBkd2Rz58jvIHbt2qXkvwpB9CpLB015SpZHS60yyFCwjJJ02dxBiG6VueuP4v7y0+ffvuPDWusWk+w8AIKQ9f84JghR7LgJok9g/xC9K1+srjDuJkFsrd8A/fnbbxI7a1GcONccHzIk5PHf/GpdeycjQ0h+9TL+g0xP7sEdf958Zvufnf/vxeRzgngKJ+tffvlFihwAd+/eRVWqVDFfsHqtrtTA0WjUqJGSff3795e2TXbiy6B169ZZtoPwgypBqPivQhB9y5ZDS3BQLLGCZUlAwNPnyJzvh2+OHlEeVyAIkd4g+9bgHYTKvLlxKlNaP9xiUlmI7OzdR6qfgCBkCIeU79y+jX777jvlvhXZ+yPe+Ycy/ivjktDty5dCjkNZwqXLf+IctfnV17JkPsNPwPM1QZi3mdbhzv2L6vy/KOlFmzZtzMTSt6/xayI4RqT7WlOfWfc3+v7775X+9gMQEVzD2kO3SXQTybf/b4F/3nq4Fab6Yt3MmTMC/WftVScIef9VCGJAGYcglpQq50i6TAWRC6LzfepDJQjl9imICIIFEISs/+YOQjSvHOzABCHTnyuqVsuyhBouNtR8Wbn/zxoxcf9t/f7YUf8xCwLjT5P8ThDmi27tpCc2YI6V2OBtaJmES5LX0iVLlN6eht/yyxCQCH4JWkQYXbp0yTkEsXOnkv8qBDGoTBRaHGliCSXNcjlb8kCfs4TREaTvqkEQwQsRlgiPzJktbM+LcrZc/cYbSguH65mZ0v47t5jkFiI7evd22ebXX8sxQTjzRm4hllULJ7b/93XprDT+a55/Ef1hPHeQXagFj7+q/3tatGT6WH2+NsuGPxqU4wjiabxSvkMNJDswLOC9B7juxo0bvufQIIPW1tp5yOL8+XNS9rD4Dm+xN2zYgBbioE3bvBn9/PPPXHtEgQGrdiWCmDEj0H92Is9R2kHslPYfMGzYMGndg0uXQ4siTSym5GLmGK+eTXCLrLJI35UjGcoJ7Mjs2R79LGgb+AQRlFDdCeg63kHI+g8EIdJHH9uOCYJnL+vfcmoHoaI/NEIJPv/YlClK439q8mSBfWrjr+r/jQP7PQTBjqd3/rj9+zg6WhME3PbZvGkT7tQ/LfxFST5atGgRUE/rMMt37vwm/adLyZvS8vpN/Pbbr2jAgP4oqlw5VDoy0kYMXgVMnDDBeHs66HrWf/h0R/Xq1UMgCK//vP6co7iDEPlPt6dCEENL00ESRcko5hgHpShZijnG01fKLF/FBKFK/BkWQQTCY4/T5qp6byqR7LXMTGn/j1kvb7oXBmzCdWAQhER/LaN2EKJ5xbb3+9276MT6dSgVL8wmvFYPTXqzPlo/aBD6z/XrSv1AcG7TRvnxx7vS2zeu+/rvt/D77dYttAsT0Yz3G6OxtWqjKW+/jTYOHYZ+uHpF2X8or6v+kjMPZOYz0/+faoIwAd9mUklAJ04ct88niRckXab17di+Xent6TFjxigQllkHPpQrWxbFxsYabcHtLJAxMTGobJkyaNy4cZIJ3DnWvXs3aZtnYILw859uz6z7E83BCS80ghATsgpBDI8si1JxUBgoRUkOFkU6khdQqVYw2tfQOqnyFYsgRAsRHkHQ7dM2iexdVe8NRYI4Ke0/jyCC4mhbr15cfaw/S1+opjTuRJ7ftw+NrPoi6vpEYdSvUFE0pEgJ9EWR4qhnwSLo89h4dP30aYk+cOu/jmNedvw3v9lAeiFmr/jPnkVDnn4GdS9YGA0sXMyweRCWydjm3qXLosy0zdL+E6R//nnwfPGZn6S+RXlNEPYnwOGzEyTJ02ATHksI3vMdSQasf79+SvZs377NVz8P8CZ0+ago35/QAllUwKsB+Fkuax9tM4v58+eHQBBe/+mJS/pPhSDgu1Mq/XGvCGIhJRcyx3gBt7CUI+nzgSCC+p3Xj0AQrH0ee6g2zXJZW66o93rguLPtwQ5C1n+HIP5UIgiR/qXGDsLPXn5c7pk5E3XHiXV40RJoVkSk7T9gQcky6MtiEWh0terGDjnIf9afW9/elB7/DOP5YTBB0G3e+eUXNOzZymhk0Qg0H9tIjyfYPL54KdQnsjT69vw5pbx0YUuay39Tb1nf+cLOr5aaIJxPgO/fv08qcP788w9b0mX/hPsHeqlmTSV7bt68GdC+N7G0b9dO+AAcbqXBw1tRIqKPpaenK95i4vvvSKesShAyhEbqVAhiRGRZ3wBaYAUrSLq80E4S9DU8uPURXM7IUF6IpM+aLWGPP1bgHYTswgDwzcmT0v4fxQsJlXm1FROETP8ueeFFpYXYf25cRz2eKIKmlogM7IsxxUqiExs2BPrPAm5ZyY7/OUq3TH/vnDIFjcbkEDSeKeBT69bShAZ1t7//XjAvWPvd87VFNvxd6hxJELDyHjRwIJPMghMcqYeVCJF0mdSfxIGm8vPWmphMgtpj7YG2yLsZIjSoX5/jDwunDXjALWv39OnTuf57YdapEcQO6fEIZQexoJQFSFRE0mWr3ghgmkCoYzL1RNfljHQJP9z1PIJg7WPtpxPOitfeUJrXBkFI+n8U7yDYhRNvXAi29uzl+ECBTxBifaTux2++QTMjSvvqI/bCKn1p+/bCecTqXxKbIDX+P165LKWPyJRXXpEi/JF4dQ+7DZE+Gisrv+A/H1kw86dFeU0QzsfwateWJABH0mU/goDPc6i8Pf3+++/buvgJ1z0R4I8ZyT7fgPPgZT+3vW5/WP9lv8/kRxB+/adCEDt27AgkSNofwNChQ+V3EKXKSBPEfKsMMhQssOSl9HROvwfj8MxZLht49gTVL3/t9cB5xOLqiRPS/h+xdxD+405jS8+eUgS3+PmqAXHmnbc/fnM1sH9oTDd0+/vPi+slFZ8Vjn9qVIzQf1r37R++R+Px7oDnPz1nADMiItHpbduk4pa0v/m99/3nIzNf2PZbaoJwEBcXh86dPYs79ndrEH9nyn4E8bsteee//dZbSnZ06NCBmUxue+g2AfCdIlndQBCXvv7ak1CD2mvYsKEkQUyT7C9TzlYkCD//s4Ig5kOgYMwrWcaW86wgmhciGQSBRxA8P2gAQcwnycmy1y5LtLm87uuB+ll7gCBk/c+YNy9gPvEJQsbmRTiJy9oLZUIQMpiCV+OwWJJd+AHgoblI76pqNaX6gOi+cPAAmo13PVJ247HeM3Wq5ELVlDu7dAnUR88ndv631LeY3LeZpk6ZIkyYbAIMqr927ZpBPCp2wBvawe25AR8cVPHx+LFjlG6x/k8//TQsgvD2j4nZs2cpfY9KltBCIQgSECKwCZM+xkUEJanypfTDnv4QjcPhmTPV7aHaXFb39UD9bD8CQci2J0cQjn4gCK6+CEcC3ATBn0d0/8HPQedL9D/IWTgp/3j9ulKcL6vxknD81771tuQ8NZGxbKmv/y4fLGzu39/Xf17c7R8yJFBfEFpGRWmCoNGkSRPj10w0oKOJpMt+9TQW4K236sf54A3qIP1s+8sUP6534MD+QH0sOnfupEgQbvj1lwpBbN++XdpeqFMhiJEUQcyNcCRdlq0XYa4lYQfBJhDT9j98x/0QhyBU7AGCIG3ItHf1xHFp/4EgxOPitJmGCWIu0yc8/akGQcjFHZSBIFTG4+b581JxTOqWvFRb2N8bPvpI6D+NQ3PnKo3nxm7dpPICQfqkyfLzk2lfEwTnFsx//vOT1bl3JfE7JX93HftMcvVNA95X8NPHa2/RokVK+vfs2R2oj20vObmHHEFMmyZlLynPnqVGEP76WNxV20FQAeFBSUryQJ+DMYeSc5hjdPnrw4eVFyJAEB79JR3Js4fG0rr1hMRKt3/l+DFp/2UIgsbm5GRu/7DtpVapKt0/gO+vXPH1n4dvMjMD9N+1JZlvS2rVEY7/prbtpPqAYP/Uqf7zjaN/fbv20gslkPCXCGX7g4UmCA5BbN68SSmBwn1MImmo/AKIxuRJk1wExOqHtokELA6JIO5K+9enTx8pvdMwQbB9wLOXQI0gtgXou+shdDWCKG0n3KxGMEHcVVqIHJox06ufIQj6GIsldV9TGvcrx49L+5mOk5BIH31sc3JPKb0mQcjZSxOErN00QYgXNjjWatcR6tzUqbPSQmn/lClKc2odJggV/fAZlFDnb6tymiA86Ne3L05AdyjcpeRd5pi3niTzjRs3KH2cj2DKlBSXflPfHV/CWLQoVZkgiA5at9tnB/DJcRWCoG3kE6jZV7NmzZQniG3bhPro8Rg6dEiWEAQ8PCSSLvvVzy5ByRJWXQnqfKv89eFDCjtUEwenz/DV59eemyDqMQuN4HGCHYSs/4cxQfAWB+6FgiM390jm9w/T3sLKLwgXYrT+765c9vWfp/9q5smAhZi7fwBAEKLx39y9u9B/GjRByMyndXiHoqL/5LJl0vOZRUtNEF7Ue+21QAIQwzy3R4/uIbXPEoSIoFQJYvfuXUoEqEoQIgINlSD8CeGOxx9VgphVwsRsSrqC0wqoWSUcSZftgLaDr4yJEqUdSeHioYPGByLBXpB02c8vIAjWHjaB0D6w/iyu85rSQufysaPS/psEcUd63m6yCMLjDwMgiKBxZvV/d/myr/+89q6ePCkdBzA2qbXqCMd/k0EQcvpA7kuZ4us/O75QXte2reTC1QQQhPR8ZvpL7yB8fu76zdWrxgf2TNyh5B3mmLceBuW3335DL1atGjJB0ImCTSRs+6mpigSxa5elz7yelJ32fnPV95P8TMi0qVO5iY7VR2yHPzCkQhCy/Q8YMkSBICLogIm0pYnSlCxt/PLFlhHMMW59pCOpMhCEf+Lj48D06U47NmgbI91tMvaJCcINIAhZ/w/NmaNEeJuSk/n9x/izIJAgvIAdhJ//PMAOQla3QRB4ByEa/43duksRPsE+vIPwHU+2/zHW2gQhh+PLl/v6zxIcO//1DsLnu0VLly5xJRwaMgnwEE4AKm9P8wgiKAHSUN5BYIJQITw1gpAnVBWC2LZtq8J43FHaQQzHATGzBB8zikfa0ihTcqZVZ0sDkZSMZI45+swdBDtvgrEfEwSrT7Y9kKmv1HXpEy0MLh09Iu0/IYigcafb2NC9h0u3X//Pr/x8QJ942/sW7yD8/Oe1d+XkiYA49iL15VeE47/BIogg/+ny3skpvv7zxndNmzaScWbiGN5B+PkvQouy5TRBcP9Oca+exi7AxK+U/NXodCLpMqmHc4cPH6b881aClJTJhg5HvyN5SE1dGCJB8MG2J0sQU6dOYfrKrYvVD99uUiEIP/95+lV2EENLRNoBxGI6JaczxwyQ5AOSLhePDAS8HCUmBXcCAIIw9QfoDrCHJQh2nNl+vHT0qLT/BzFBiPTRIAQh6r95BkEEJ0Aa316+pDQeV06cCLDXuzBbiAlCNP7ru3YT+k/j7M4daE+v3hZ6+UinfHzRIulFBUsQqvhMEwQfr9erJ00Q3gT7K3rzjTdCbtskiGD9NCGlLlQjCPjjOw6Z8eBO8Ko7CB5h8ggD/gKd2g7Cj5DdgLohQ76Q1j2kBJUASzjSTsQl/AlDBEga06kEQspAECI/2H7bN22aVz+TsIMSOhBEkH52nn99JEPa//2zZwsXBixB8PvL3f9zn3ve1z7euN+89HUgobH2Xz5xXFo/1C2wdhBBYy5LEKrjL+M/b+F6dOlS6fnL9r8miICvu8JfjPv11189gI4nki6T+gsXzhvXh04QKS59bHssspogWH+kdxBTpkj1z6+//mLIGTOmS9u8ZcsWAam5oUIQg6kAmUZJA8UoWcyqK+YfYOz19DH62nP79wvH1UsQ0y0dpTz6ZOxbaBDEb0oEIeu/SRDBCYyeB+u7defqY/tvzrNVfHeOvPaAIALHh+kvNYL41SAI0fiv79pVKq5Ux1/Gf971QBCy84Xt/081Qfg/h9i6dYudzBz5K3PMixnTp4d8e8l4D2LypED9LBYuXKCkH76MKqsboEYQPB38/lMjiDQlm7/4Qo0gpsmCSZiuYwrnA0GI5hHbb3vxDs2rv5Qj6bJVP9Uqg5xf+1XBPHa3ZxCEpD/7Z82SWBg4MAhCor/m4B2En72m7l+o9n6xCILvv1EuFmlLwKXjx3399/rzC5oPBCEY/3UWQQT5L5NHRHmH5z+RNI4sWeLrv2j+NtcE4Q/4Cusvv5idTKRZvm1LukzqmzVtGla78KJckH4PQSxQJ4ggfbTPgH79+oZFEGx/mXpvG0QqTRBpadL2KhNECSqBUEmFl2CmkjJIukzqBSC6zu7fJxxXFntw/3p1RlIykjnmrp+PdxBB+tlxupiRLu3/vpkzhf7Q+td168bvX8af2XgHETTOdFwCbnx90df/qcXImDoJ8NLxY9JxDZj3cm3h+K/t0kWqf1XHX8Z/HkyC4PvvIVBm/n+iCcIfPZOTqaQmjxdffDGsdlMmT7aTqAxUCQI+fKfiD3w8UPbXVyp6VQlCRfcXXwyW1j0IE8QUHBQygOCaIpmQeSDXnsMEIUoYbD3sIGgbePYE1QNBBOln2weCkPUfdhB+CwFeQluLCUKmf2c/+7x0/wCuX7wQ2D/seAFByCZsqAOCEI3/2s5dhP7L9L9qvR+OLF7ka+8USvLwsSaIAILo2dPo4Nu3b9uSLpMBYOtr1qwRVruT8A7i9u1bvu2xWLBgvhpBbN9u6bxlgJTDJoiUFJ/+ucVtT4Ug0gIIgtUPbQ8eLE8QnxeXJ4gpRSmJkULJFKuOSLrM1p/Zt084rix24/6V1c+zfd4rryq1dz79sLT/sIOQGRci13YlBBFJyUjmWCk085kqwnnEEoSf/7z++vrYUel5BeW5NWsLx3+NRRBB/svEtYw9QXFLdKcvWhTSfAF8pAkimCCcwfXHrVuOBMj+gR1/gpgo1S5BKAShor9v3z7SD9fpvhDpha+/yhPEZiWbVQhiAEUQbAB5UIySxZhjvHofnNm31xPg3oTihgxBBLU/t3YdKkl5wdpz/vBhaf/3zJihND5runaV6r+Zz1SWthfKhCB8+55p7+LRI4H62PGYg3cQovEHgpDpA9XxV7/eLANB+Nkrmk/NNEGICeLWrZ9tSZcdgnDXh00QEycGtsdi/vx5Svrhw3dEt4x+2Y/1wc9zZfqHYNq0qdI2wwcU/QnaOz6DBw+S//YWJojJOBgmW0ExmUqIk4uWtKVRLlbKlnSZ1E+2zy3FlN31X+3da9krP867MEGw+rz2OJJtf84rdQQLHXc/AkHI+i9DEPTiYXWXri5b/fpzBkUQojgEXLtw3td/3vjQBCET50AQovFf7UMQ7EJSdfxl/OcBCMJ/frrBzv+mmiCCCCLZk9RkkBUEEaT/55//Y0tAuAQhgipByEKVIPz8p48RhEoQk4qUtCVdlk04svhq7x5pIiUwCcKtR2yvgzm16lBJyZugWJw7dEjafyAIlbEnBOHxx9IJcpJFECp6vzl/ztd/Hi4cOaKkf3bNWsLxX925s5Qu1fEPFempqdL9wc4nTRABSE5OtpOQCsIliIkTJyi1N3+eGkHAS2cq+vv06S3981zzmp8o+RNzzAG8WCdr86ZNG5VsHjRIniD6FHcCwkhMRBooRUkOipR0JA+sPqt8es9uj80s0bFECATh0km3bdtE2+y2YbZNEHJEe/bQQWn/90yfLtRHH1uFV9ky/T39meek+wdw9dxZX/957V04kqGkf1bN2sLxX9Wps7Q+wJmDB9HGCRPuGZa1aSucj371H5bV32IKmyDgDwwRCcgKgiA6efrpY6ESBH19lhHEpEm2jTRYe0MlCJE+Bz8pEUTP4k5ATCziSBnQ1/Cuh+QxkZPAgSDYcfX2myMBOydPdukM0s+zZ3atV2yd/H50EzsQhKz/uy2CkJ23q7p0kerv6ZUq+y40ePqvnD3j6z8P59IP+/rPW9jMqlFLOP6EIERxS8rrx45FLR4pwEVLSrZkjvHqWUBd/yeKhDx/G2uC8EePHj3QTz/9aAwkkXQZJK8+XIKYMGF8oH4Wc+fOUdIPLwC6dfxISdLmj3b7vXuHRxAsiC/w3oSszfC3NUT66P4aNGig/DgXLyVNCCwmUJIH+hy6zCMIUYLdgfvXT59fezRMgviP1BgBZAiCtLVz2jShPtqnlXgHEdQ/xJ+plZ6TtheSORDEBIXxA4KQsZeUWYLgjf+Kjp2k9YHcNm4cmlA4wsB4SvJAn8M7n60HhDq3AY3KldcEoUoQXrgTbNYThCN5UCaILVts3Tz9oRPERO71fvrVCYLvv7c9NYLoignCDjAcFETyQJ8jc74fMnftdI2BDLZjghDpDbJvFiaIoHFm5/lXB/ZL6weCEC2c6GMrO3WR6qepTz/n2x88/YQgZMfnXPohKXsJZlR/WagfCEJWH2Dr2HHK8yer5qfo/IZRmiACCeLHH39QRlYQBOghE4iU/dpTJQj4bAWtj26D117v3r2kH67L6PvpJ1NOnZKiRBB+/hN9IElZhSA6YYLwC5jxpAySnKMQYH71IREE7l/WHpeNvPYpOdMiCFkAQcj6v3PqVKv/f7THwSl7dROCGF+4pC1NRFAyAk2p+KySzZfPfOXrP6+/zh4+rKR/Ro2XheO/vENHof8sQfj570EY4y91PuPP25og1AmCl5CIzAqCGD9+nKXrews/UNLbfigEQesTQZUgZDFFgSA2bFjv6z8LVYLoUCLSCdAilMQYZwUUSB7g3HF2UJd0HQuqz9y1wzNvRNhmEcQ4KkGw9gXZM+PlV5Tm8en9+6T9B4IQ2U+3sbxTZ669bP+nYIKQXxh8jwnidPB4MP135tAhX//dsWeWp1d/STj+QBAqeWPL2LHS8y+c8edd72qT0359TRBBBNEd/fDD9xL4jpLfZQlBgD4yMUnZr/05c2YrEsRml34WbHu9evWSfrju7gu3LlY/vHmtQhByY2Fi4MDPpXW3KVHKNwGOLehIuuycU5KSJZlj/ji5c4eH+GUIIhx7WIIwx+EH33ECgpBtbwcmCK8+pw024S7v2Ilr71irDBLgJojvAxdO0Nalr04HjsdYSgKAIPz8540PEISov5e17yj0ny4DQfj5T9ucFfOR9Z/Vz+J1TRAyBOEmADYBsgibIMaNC9T//fff2RKgShBpaZsoX76z9H1n66PbMAmipwJByPeXEkGsX+/rP+0DaUeFIFqUjPQPSCagPChIyYLMsYAAP7Fjh6efROOwdfx4fzsk7Jn+cm3XuHvHxW3PqX17pf3fjneDorigsaxDJ25/sZiMCUJl3L8+nRk4Hiy+OnjA138vvkfTgCAE/b2sfQelhWXal1+Kx1UWgvkoAjtfX42O1gThh+7du+EJ+C0H31HyO+bYt2ETxLhxY136vO25MWf2LCX98NJZsH63P9IEMWG8lD6ClJRJ0javX7/W13+v/u/Q558PkNb9MSaIL3EQyQCC58uAgKPPMVCYkka5hCGPbd9m2Pndd98G+kH3Y5pFEKDDt70Ae4EgVOZV5t490v5vx2TvN84Epq+mXNqho+1HkD+TnnpGadwvnjoZaC/dJuD0wf0K+r9FU6vVFI7/UkwQIv/JuIPcPGZMwHiWoKRp+4JX66G1rVobWNPSkTxAXerr9X39d7fhRe0KFTRBBBEEGUw3blLSi7AJYuyXgfpZzFYliE2bKB94/nzrqodPjsg9XB/Hvd4P8GKdrM3r1q0J6INvPf6oEESTkqWpBE5JLtwBKwowPxzHBMEmDBZ0UgEAQbD2jbHaBjnGIh8i6TLIqTVrufR5E5a7PR5B+Pm/LWWyREJ0pEkQ4n6ahHcQsvZCGQjCz3+6r4h+IAg/fTx/CEEEjf/Sdh2k7QUJBOHbB54FRgQ6MG16oD52HqXPn+/rP08/Pb9qxsRogvBDt27d0LffmkmISLoMklcfLkGMGTM6UD+LWbNmKhLExkB9rH/du3dXIgj2ej/AexOyNq9du0baXigPGCBPEI0iy9gBNMZOthFMWbZeBPPco9u2CseVRdq4cb76ZOw1CcK/31ic2LNb2v+tkyd7rg+KmyXtOxrXjbauB0mXif6JeAchG3eAC5knBfa6cerAPuE8pdtLwQQhGv9Frdsq5Y1NmCD8/Ofp3zolRSovEOyZO8fXf9H4Vo2N1QQRTBA30M2bN2xJl0Hy6mvUqB5Wu8OHD1NqT5Ug4Cej9PUs2PY6deok/eyEdz0LUgdfrZUmiDVrfP3ntTdgQH9p3W9HlrUDVAQ2gEUJjq0nAIIwbb1J2X2Tkjc99UAQqu3Rx6bWqBWon23/xO7d0v6bBHHDSlp+/jhY3L6DVP8CQcj2D+D8yRNK/ZO5f5+UvaQupWoNYX8v+KyFtD6QG0ePDiAIN6Bu27Rpvv7zsGvWLOF89EOVMP50cr4gCDMJXaekGOESxOBBA136zAR4nUqQzjHA3BAeUgf7QPt8A7Vr11aSIMZyr/f2n1lWI4jVvv7zoEIQb5YpJx0woygZCsi1R7Zuke4nUr9p7FiXDTx7gupTqr+s1N7x3Tul/U/Du0HvYsM/bha3a2/pjKBkBHOsBBr/ZCUpfaTu3Injgf3DAgjCz39e/0x+vppw/Oc2/UjaXpDmDoLvP298t8+cKRW3pLxzxgzhfPSb75USEjRB+BNEV3TjxjUOrlPyOnPsGqpePTyCSO7RI1A/2/6iRalK+nft2knp5ul3o1mzZtIP11X6a9LECdI2r8EEIdv/UO7fX54gXi0XZQfMyILFbUmXR4VBCjyYBOEOcLCbSLpM6oEgwmkzpfpLlk5+P7LtAUHI+p82caLnetBNt0cfA4KQsdkkCLn+gTIhCFl8lXHYV593fK6hiZWrCnVOf+ttof80YPelYvPOefN8/ef1D/zCTFY3PedHYCQlJmqCEBHE9evf2JIuk4Fn68MliFatWgW2x2Lt2tVK+jNwUFy/Lq//rbfekn64zu8fRzrtXjN+Fitr8+rVK33t441P//79pHW/VD4aB0QJPgoUd2QBK3gKOAmTPuY61+d6gvS0NLsfZMdh45dfqttDYXK1l+yxkOnHY7t2SLe3GROEn17ePEht206qv8ZhgvCzj55LRPeZ48d8/ee1d+F0ZuA8Yufx+EqVheM/AROxyH/a9h1z5/jPF07/7Fmy2Nd/enxJGW5N+uoLwCBMEE8++aQmCN9v9HTtgq5dMycLkXQZJK8+XIJ49913LZ1XDZCy0/5VV316+iFp3ZUqVUJXr15m/HHrM/26avsne8uMEATbP26dTlsqBAEPqf3tdQPqVAiiaoUKdlCMsIIHJF2WrReBnJuetplKdHy/2HHfMGaMrz5iDwv6nMk4cQXNI3bcj+7cLu3/5kmTpMaFSCAImf4dl1RJun+gfOb4UV//WYwpUYax0e2/N+6voi8TKorHPy5J6D+No9u3Ks2vQ+vXSuUFgvXDRyjPT5C9MUFkR97NZQRxVRnhEkS1atXQN9/ItwcJv2rVF6R0N2jQwNYNki7zdH/99QWUKLnNHIsJgtYl0j9pkhxBwC0uk9Tk+0SFIJ6NjUXDCxQzAIFBpAESrCA5MM61JA+sPlI+vHmT8rwCgqB1cu0NwKRqNV1ELcKRHdul/J8Qm2Tc2mEXAkFY2KadVH+PTXpaqY/OHDsi1ReAKc+9EKiLN49Hlo8Vjv/nBYqiy5cuStt8+eJ5NKpoKf58o49ZfZV5YJ+kbnMsVvcf4NsHQfOpayFNEIHo0qULnhhXlBEuQSQkJKCzZ79SarNNm9ZSuuH9ABW9O/EqUnabOfbLMUq6ZT7WV6dOHZSZeUJ5DPr16yvf57i//RJ8+ChOSad8eNNGTHqmrSDpsp9P60ePltbPs2UiJgizjcsGSNmvvWO7dwn9G4kT2xG8u+NdT7fBtregTVup/hub+LSvfTz9p4+k+/rPAv6QTpD/PAwtFinUOwQjA+8Kgvynxxrk3DcbSNk8DhMUq0s0nks6dw5p7rYtUkITRDBBdEZXrlwyOp1IugySVx8uQSQlJRkPZf30s4A6OF+k9+mnn0YH8OqDdz3tDw2VL66OGT3K10Zee0sWLwrUB++T7Nu3R8p/djz69u2j1N+DniiGhlmBMYwKEvpYVuKQQRCiBOKuXztqlHI7tA8TqlZXau8rvBoP8n84XtnCX5KTGXMPQbRuK9XfX2KCUNF/LvMkGlmsNNd/Vv9hHDNB/rP9cwmv9AdL9vvqsWMD/Wfb2zNnjtR8W9mho1T/0pjx3vvS85k+p3mxCE0QMgTB4upVR9JlUh8uQQCGDh3CbTsIrVu3Fu4eVHV27NhB2uYRw4cp6T516qRBWtxfFr36qkEOqvaSsVAhCNghJWOCGFrAi2GUHMYc49WLQM49uHGDsl9rJAiCtY/G2MpVlducgBM0z//heOewe9q0kMYHMK9VG6n++zLh6YBx5i/c0nHiH1MuJnA857xRX9nmzPRD6IvHi0qN/9SPPlHWP/fNfweO7ZgyFdCZoxlC/1m9w2KTpOczjfdLlNQEISKIy5e/5uAiJS8yx77OEoJ4+61/+7Tt3/6ZM6dRhw7tPboqVqxo3JO/iFdA/jr5gOchsjYPGvi5cn8NHjzIs8uBT5wAeaj6T5+jQhCAdoWKc4MkXAyhJF0+sGG98lisGTlSWj/PltFPPaPc5pbRYzx6UqpUQ0fxDiiUcSEgBCHyZ0xCRWWbAWfx7mdxs4+xLu+4wucyINGq6tyPx0x23PtGxQT6z8N5POfnvfsedzzHxiSgjPXrlG0+uncPGvBYkZDmboOSkZoggtC5cyepiX/p0kVbArKCIOLj49GRI+m2Thp0m9yJvH8Pmjp1Cho9eiSaMWMaSk8/bNjL0xWkP23zJuN5iKzNvXomW9dftCVddvS761evXoXGjBmFpk+fhjIy0j39qeo/6FQliE+KlrCD0oXHKfk4cywUPO4QhMhPFqstghgSkFCD7B9ePi6wH/3s2Tt/Plrerj1a1aUb2r8o1fjhAn9cROPutDG3ZWup/hyd8JT0PODZf/rQQZQ2fIRh/8qOndCuGTPQxfNnlfwn2IDnp+z493msMNqN57Wf/0HtHcG7y/X9+qNlmERXdOiIdqakoAt48ReK//P790eD8a4nlPlbu3QZTRCBf2msUycjGMQ4T8nzWUIQ8MuhL74YLNm+Gi5dciQPpK5Txw5Kv4Nu26Y10xf89uhj9wp9+vRW6u9GxSPQFzhwVAGB9AUVcPQxAwUoSZX3rVurPE6rR4zw6lewZ2CRksw4nLelzLj5zZNQxmdOy1ZS/WcSRNbMG+88VPM/tW9f6f4ejFft45o0zdI4VfUf7hj0ik8KnC9BqBoVpQlCjiDcBMBOJBbVq1fLkvafe/ZZ47YRb+CJ5IE+R+Z83vUZeNeRlKj2mn3jxo257UFfEcnrP+/5bvtD8V/272gT1I8oFZjQ/YIIVmdE0mU/gjDqLIIQ++Hut5XDhwuD2mMP1ebAx4ugr04eCxgXN+hzeOeL6oPiBAhCpr9GYYLwa08079m4Fdsb7P/Eho2Uxr/zE0XRsQN7w5jHwf0t8n/dtCmox6OF7PGXmc/0Oc9kw5dccxlBdEQXLpzz4OJFR9JlUp9VBBEXF2c8WFZtn61nITofyu3bt5N+/4GgVq1aUvap+gO32uDntir+y/6ZVNt2vJ0mQa4CNsGxCcMPe9ausmw+Kz0uQBDG9Xh1Goqtg/B1+zauD3me+I3bubOn0cGtacLzwVciZ7doIWXzyPgnw7Yvq+KkX4V4pfHv+2hhNOr9D7j+k3FXGX8V/8+czkSdsb2DQpwrn2MkZMOH+nIZQXRgBpU/0CyyiiDg9k6F6Gi0efNGQ+/58yZI2a99+hz++W5/zLpz9vnLli1B0eXLh3Rb7DSemF6bRP3nX38Sr3jrvFIbLVmcquS/KkFUxv4aSZQkUz/ggLMlXWaupZPyYOp8UgaCUB23lcOGee1j7KHb5LW/etLEkOcJb96fP38GDXv7HbR01EilOJndoiW/vxl/RsQ/FWCvM3ft+ZJxGO1ctVLKPxX/925Yj3rihK86/q0fLIA2zJ7pO1dVxl/GfyJT2rZDXR8p5Bl/Fp75YskuePcDP//WBBEA+InnuXNnjCAg0ix/ZUu6TOpVfvkj89JclcqVjc9pEP0saBv59gbX09i7dxeqaL0bEMr7G6tXrfC0Z/aT01/uY/72Hjt2BL3xxusopkIFtNggCHn/Zf8Knt3PeLc2wAr0gVTAD6SODZSoZzGIknRC2bV6pWfeiPxaNnSoUD99jFc/rVUbX/2icWJx9swpNPrDpuizhx5HK0aOlBhXJ1ZmftaC37+MvcPxDsKvfd48Prp/L2oREYkO79ymHBdB/o9r/ikaAAShOP798TWfFY5A+/EiT5Q3ROMv4z9g7bQpqPmDjwXOP9H8/rRQ9nyHKVcRRIcOHYw3ms/iLbQjTzPHvPVZSRCAmJgYVO+119DRoxmS9ojAXm/i0KH9qAbe/cCtrVBt7Y0Ts9ged/sQJESSckbGIWPnADsomKiLFi0MsN/bnipBwO6nW0Cg2yDngKTL9jlFKVmUOeYACIL2XWZeOQQhYaePvf2TKiqMgyPZ8786dQINxTuHT3Ai6o/1r8QEIfKH1gkEIWP/MLyDCJon7vbwvNm7G3V9uCBqU74COoRJwj3Hg/vXz//0PbtQ+wJFQx7/7ngl3yYqGh3asc3Wybdf1T6v/2k4Tj4pYN7ekrOXj4ZFS2Rb3s1FBNHe6HR4UEwkXSaDwtZnNUEA4JbPq3VeMZI4294ZvJJz5CnmGA/u80HXrl070ItVqxpkFO6Ddbgt5O6fU7aky371mzZtQM9XqWKTA+hdlLrQt795/vfsmax8O++zgsXQ5zg4AvEoJXmgz+Gdb5V3rlwhnEds/dIhQ6T1+9kPyXNz6gLJec0ft6MH96Ne1Woaq9R+jxQ22lthEQQN7zg5mP7pZ4Y9Ay27BjJlYu/Q2CTpeUQIAuzp8PATqFW58mgvnkuycevn/+D6/0Y9cZIPZ/w7PvQEalGyDNq5dk3Y9vj5v372LNSsQGHU/eFC8vPXZ77ULVlKE4SYINqhr77KxDhFSXNwiDTLmbYE3AuCgAQGJPH00xXRkiWLXPa4bZSx15GAWbNmGA+kYrLgD5TD+xvdunWhbMl09RGvv2jAHx0CO1hbUnFS8/OP53/Pnj2UbX+/aHHjNgIECEgTRShZxKpzAok+xqv3w44Vy5T6BbDkiy+U2x9ASQAk9C5PVUKZmMRZ/TL2ALm0LFsetXjoceP2CWlr2YgRvnbzML35p1L2D8EE4a/HOw8O49U+ub4jJolmBYui1VOn+swTsf+z+/VDLR98PEvGvxO2p8ljBdHcgQOV4yLI/1Mnj6OUTp3R+/98FO9WCgaOv2Fn0Hyx5v+LZcpqgpAliNOnT9qSLpOBYuvvBUEQkoDEWToyEn388UfGL3tCsY9gM15dNXqvISpTujSKzaK/PQs2RpUrh0aNGiFsn7YXHsS/887bhi28W1wLF843HoADTF2ZvvqhnJysThB1I0p6CIEkQZBG2bqvTAKOPtbfIpX+Nrm4j9HYvnyZZa//uHkIYvBgZXtYwLXtHiqABr3ZAGWeOOrSHzSPMvbvRWOafYQaPfgoavtgAU97y0YMFyY0euymfvKplP00QXjnUSYlzXMO7d7pur4TXrm//8AjaHijxujIgX2ueeO1z9F/6tQJNL17d9Tkn4+gvo8UzrLx74JJ4gOss0ulZ9GGeXOUxp/1H742sGpqCmobG4+a4HHpgXc5MuPfn5rf7kWQU07KgsVinicISFjjx49VRuXKle+pXbBKL1e2LCpbpoyR4KfhSQK3nmBSA8gEdyaSc2zfvt1o4sTxqEGD+gbRQDJPzOK/GgX6wLZmTZugLWmbbLt49i1Zkoo++qiZcX75qChfW7p36yrd/xMwPvzwA2W7q5Qth/obyaCIKUlieKSwb8D1t5N1EUmY587o0gUtGjUSLRo5wpR0GSQH43CS8+gT2uu1D3YRcHuoE95JrJs90zM+NHZtWIvGtWiJmhYojJrixNb94YJc/8d/0MTXbh6G13rFxz76GF7NRkYp6Z3Tv7/H/2Rs80f/fAz7UARNbNMW7cGLkSCfoU+6VX4efYiJpSdekWf1+PfG+lrgXUmjBx5GHRKfRLP69EG7N65zxUYQdqxdjab16IHaRMcaOlphwu7zcCHp8Q8EvrYz/MQ1G/7UaK4jCLgfD0lUFffj52GwUodVPyR4aBMSLPxhH0iMXTp3Qn369EKff97feGgMP9d9v9F7xjMGYiMk4/h7+DtnSPRAYtDWyy+9hFq1bIH69O6FBgzoh7p27Ywav9/I+LUU1MN5IluIn7IIhfTi8Hj3xsEECbTfoyaMhBoQYP2sBG1cwwOjj5Sb/vNR9N4/Hkbv4QC3JUYjnJSIpMsg4baOSydPPwuf8/vg1Sbog7Y/K1MODf73W2hS+/ZoKl41T2zbFg15tyFqExNntA0r3vZ419H3kcK+/n+GCcfwgwXjHynDLoRnP9vfyThBE/9dunz0N8a28vzvixNoe9wm+ALnt0tIQkPfa2T7PK5VKzQQ76o+jSxr1H+K/ellrMjvzfiD7P5QQWMMiH/NS0aintVropEfNjHGYGq3bgaA1EZ88CFKrlYDfVK8lHEu7Irg1lcP3D+hjH9QfdMnimbbL5hyFUFAJ0GyV8X97lxIhkAW8IyC7CzgVg0kSpDwf0iwUA/n3a/fN0M/wO0iaJe2idgDt8tkVyr3YwygH1sXMBMCJEMZkHNJwNHHePUEvXHyAfR62JFGmZK9rToiIal79RexZT8rmTnSaw+LHnh1DSvQjx581EiehBCAwCABdcZJDFanIv/7+PlDHaMB53P7i5JmmeoHrv7CtjRRKNB/8KUzPDDGvoGPjSmfoQ/gvQXok3s9/vT50BddcD9D283xTqcJtusDbBOQwPvYLiiDrbDrg3O6POyMSbjjz7P/9Wz6zHeuIwiN/AUglfcKFpNODqGAJPk+VMInMivOz+nQ/ud8/1+MLK0JQkODh9rFSzqr94chKAvbki7zVvjmyriwLbnnsyB11gq4DyV51wvtEYGx13WMA+1//vIfdmOJ0dGaIDQ0eKhYtpx924J/y8cd0PRtDt4tD1G9SyfTJg+sPez5qvqF9mr/85X/LR8rnK0PqDVBaORowDOTdo/6B6iGRl5Gg0LFsvUBtSYIjRwNeMD9ZsFiqCcOFgMPFXQkXbbqe1HSKD/kSAMPU/Jh5thD7mvkrmfseagQJTn6KClzvbA97X+e9r9SZGS2x6AmCI2c/bAaB0kyHVQUkh9ypImClDQDLTkg4SRbAUrOd+twt8FrryclZfTTx7j6mPZE0P7nXf9bPVY47E/taILQyPOAIGlSoDDqgQOLBQRTDyqgkx+m5MNWnSV559PHZOpF7Xv1OZKXgLK6fe1/3vG/ZtHiWf7SrCYIjTx5m+nZEhG+QRqMQpQsxByTqVfVJzj/wYKOfNA658Fw9Gv/86L/7R4phKLLls0R8acJQiPHA17ug11EdyuYQNJlEmBsvQjC6x+i5EPMMR5E5zP1PSjJa19kn/Y/b/pfo0ixsD7zrwlCI18BfuqXEBGBuuAA6hZGQLL13SjJQ3dBe90edCTvfFY/fc29sEf7n/v9b/5oYVSuTJls//WSJgiNXLeLqFOwGBPET1DyCdSVkl2tuq72OQVdx3j1IoiuV9Ufrj3a/7zlf2eMxBIROWb3oAlCI1c9iygTGYmaPOoEVFc7uAoyZb96EUTXu+tFCULcvqo+Ftr/vOT/y0WKGx/uzElxpwlCI9fA+AhiyZKo5b8Koi5WcHWhApA+FgrC1Zf19jiyK3NM+5+3/H+7QGHjA5o54ZdLmiA0cvWtpviICNQ2pCRQkJIFmWNedKZkZ+ZYVpwvskddn/Y/N/r/waOFUJlSpXLUrSVNEBq59iuvxh9WKhGBWj/kBCMXDxRwJF226jtZZZB0OVCngn5l3Gd92v/s978xJoeymBxisvGvxmmC0MhzzyPgb23E4Z3EJ/9yArzTg5R8kDkmkQDYhMHqM+oelE8w9DU8e1h4rmftEUH7n6v8/zfcVsLkUCGbv9iqCUIjz5JEVMlS6J3HChsB19EKvI4+oM/hnS+qD1cfm3A6PuDIrDhf+587/Ie/plezcDHjD3YBOeSUn7RqgtDIcyRB/vzpC0WKGX+NrcM//AP6foPYApIuZ9f52v/s9//DhwuihBIRxpzNCd9a0gShkeefScD9Wwg42E3ULVAUtXngcTMoSXA+wJT/UUCuXgRV/SxU7bnX+rT/98x/uBUKi5jSpUoZf+b3Xv4Nek0QGhqct63hlhMQRfmSJVGtgkVR8wefQO1hS/8PEx0ecCRdJvUsROer6rvn+h+g5APMMe3/ffe/HUZjvGN43iIGmJvwK7z79XfoNUFoaDC7CXhXAlZoEIyAJ4uXQHUKFDYCFXYW7f7xOBXAj9uSLoda384um8mhPSV58F7vhqo9Iv3h+qf9F/v/2YOPo3ceLYRqFCqKKkSUtOch3ArN7r8OpwlCQ8MiCvhNOXk+YQN+ToiDtlKx4sZ2/6WCRVA9TB7/fqQgavSvJ9BHDxVALR94zDfhuY/x6hn87+OOpMuh6vPAfX3b/3VkW6udtv/rr48+h75W+++1py0k/38+jpriOfIeni/1HytkLDyACKrgufQUXojAzpWeb/DiG+wYciMxaILQyDcPso03sHGgwi0oCFoXaXBQDl5aKhFh7D6eLYrJpHBRVBOTySs4Ibz+WGH0Fk4Q7z38BPrwXwXRxw9C4iiAWj1gJSYq4XhA6qyE4zn/H5T8B3NMQl87SvISoFC/yD5Vf3Kg/22whEVAc7zSb4bH7oN/FUDv4rFsgFf9dfH41sKobiX9Snjsk/AcgEVFGesWURBgbsGiBJ6JwTOGnPzrJE0QGho+uwv4nAGs6mCXAb8kgYAGAoHv4ACJ0LeoVABJBFaRsRERKAEnlorFSqBncJKBZPNC4WKoGk48NTFqPVEY1caJCBJSPUw4bz5aECeoguhtnKTexuTT0CAgc1fTGOMDvGptgtEUJzRIah9hQvoY4xO8ogU0x+T0KcZnGC1w8mvxDxOtMFpaki0DWlOSLXOB9beypAHqGK2/JSnjOqMM8p+WbdhusLW5ZTsAfPkI/LJ8bIKTNpDv+1g2wsm7IQYkcegbIGdI5m88VhDVxX1Xx0rqsBuExP4ixvOY0J+zEjyQPPxqCJI8/IihtESi5yV+mBOQ/GGOwE9TYc7AwgOIAOZSbnquoAlCQyMLiASCniYTSAiEUCBJQLKApAEgxCKzQ9HIHpBEb7w/YyV7WBiQhA9jSyd9GHuYA3lhJ6AJQkMjB5ELTTCEZACQfACEcAgM4sGoAImKAiQvAkhmPECiCxeE6GSRFW3yfKH9tRM3gdVHJJEDoB8BpF9JP5N+z+8JXhOEhoaGhoYmCA0NDQ0NTRAaGhoaGpogNDQ0NDQ0QWhoaGhoaILQ0NDQ0NAEoaGhoaGhCUJDQ0NDQxOEhoaGhoYmCA0NDQ0NDU0QGhoaGhqaIDQ0NDQ0NEFoaGhoaGiC0NDQ0NDQBKGhoaGhkW34f7hDNEqgPXW8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ntknz/

Comment: :) I think you're taking the OP too "literally" ;)

Comment: Wanted to give a tip to every one who didn't know this ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your element is not an inline element, because you can't define height or width for inline elements. If it's inline, then add a rule to make it a block element:

The whole code looks like this:

```
.className{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Your containers should have specified width and height if they have no contents inside them.

```
.img{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: url(Your image location OR url);
background-position: center center;
} 

<div class="img">
</div>
```